# exit code from lualatex when characters are missing

Tags: errors, luatex, compilation-error

When pdflatex encounters a character it cannot encode into a font, it dies and produces a non-zero exit code. By contrast, lualatex happily produces an exit code of 0 and simply prints a warning:

```
Missing character: There is no ȳ (U+0233) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
```

I regard this as a fatal error, since it failed to typeset the document. I cannot find any way to make lualatex produce a non-zero exit code in this case, so I have to parse the log file looking for these.

This seems like a gross oversight of lualatex - are there any other cases where it fails to typeset the document but still produces an exit code of 0?

Comment: set `\tracinglostchars=3`

Comment: That's not true: also `pdflatex`, by default, would have exit code 0 if a character doesn't exist in a font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior of `pdftex` and `luatex` is exactly the same as regards to this kind of problem.

If I try, from a terminal,

```bash
pdftex '\char233 \bye' && echo $?
```

the console would print

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]</usr/
local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on texput.pdf (1 page, 8175 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.
0
```

With

```bash
luatex '\char233 \bye' && echo $?
```

it is similar, but the console doesn't show the `Missing character` warning.

The difference is that `\tracinglostchars` is initialized to 2 for `pdftex`, but to 1 for `luatex`. It is initialized to 2 for `lualatex`, though.

You can, in both cases, set

```
\tracinglostchars=3
```

at the beginning of your file and instead of a warning you'll get an error and the exit code will be 1.

Comment: I guess I was misled by this error message from pdflatex:
! LaTeX Error: Command \DJ unavailable in encoding OT1.